# va_arg begins by the second parameter on mac (clang++)

Tags: c++, macos, parameters, arguments, clang

the code

```
TextureMeta(string tex_, int args_, const char* ...)
{
    va_list vl;
    va_start(vl, args_);
    for (int i = 0; i < args_; i++)
    {
        string img_(va_arg(vl, char*));
        cout << img_ << endl;
        images.push_back(img_);
    }
    va_end(vl);
}
```

on MSVC it works fine but on MacOS the generated application got segmentation error,
i can see the code prints the second parameter first and the log says `TextureMeta(this=0x000000010174d680, tex_="resource/skybox/mitsuumi", args_=6, (null)="resource/skybox/mitsuumi/right.jpg")`, it seems that the first va parameter becomes the function argument and cant be iterated.
Im using CMake and the generator is default.

Is this a mac clang bug?
Or is there somthing standard undefined in above code?

Comment: Any reasons to use C-ellipsis, instead of `std::initializer_list<const char*>`?

Comment: *Is this a mac clang bug?* -- Advice -- Always assume it is your code that is at fault, and not the compiler.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie [The First Rule of Programming: It's Always Your Fault](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault/)

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili -- Yes.  Also, if the code above really and truly is a compiler bugs, thousands of programmers around the world would have noticed and reported it.  The OP should realize that C++ compilers are one of the most stress-tested tools out there.  Jumping to "is it a compiler bug?" as the first response is not a good habit to get into.

Comment: Note that "works fine" is the most common, and evil, manifestation of undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
TextureMeta(string tex_, int args_, const char* ...)
```

This is short for

```
TextureMeta(string tex_, int args_, const char*,  ...)
```

It means that you have 3 regular arguments before the ellipse. What you want is:

```
TextureMeta(string tex_, int args_, ...)
```

[<kbd>Live</kbd>](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/5z6Yb4)

Comment: Why is `const char* ...` valid syntax?

Comment: Answered my own question: [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic) - "*To declare a variadic function, an ellipsis appears after the list of parameters, e.g. `int printf(const char* format...);`, which may be preceded by an optional comma*". It's just typically after a named parameter so seeing `const char* ...` looks really strange.